# how to use straight_join in cakephp?

Tags: mysql, cakephp, join

I write codes as seen below when joining two and more tables in cakephp:

```
    $options['joins'] = array(
        array(
            'table' => 'table2',
            'alias' => 'tbl2',
            'type' => 'inner',
            'conditions' => array(
                'tbl1.customer_id = tbl2.customer_id' ,
                "tbl2.del_flag = 'N'" ,
            )
        )
    );
```

That continues with more tables included in the join.

How do I write the code if I wanna use 'straight_join' instead of 'inner join'?

Changing the 'type' above into 'straight' doesn't do anything.

Is it possible in cakephp?

Thank you for the help.